# Emulate a text-mode DOS program using a Unix terminal

Tags: emulation, terminal, software-recommendation, dos

Is it possible to run a text-mode DOS program in an emulator under a Unix-like operating system (Linux/*BSD/macOS) such that DOS text-mode input and output is done on a Unix terminal instead of a separate GUI window?

The purpose would be to allow the DOS program to run in a terminal environment that is familiar to Unix users and integrates well with their usual workflow, including working copy/paste.

Comment: "-noconsole (Windows Only)

    Start DOSBox without showing DOSBox Status Window (console). Output will be redirected to stdout.txt and stderr.txt"

Comment: Nice! The existence of `-noconsole` shows the DOSBox programmers have been thinking along these lines at least a little.

Comment: Use `dosemu -dumb` or `dosemu -t`. Both work on a server I use with connectbot, `ssh` and `screen`. (I'm using dosemu2.)

Comment: Related, but not an answer to this question: https://github.com/jhallen/cpm is an emulator with tty output for CP/M.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As [ecm](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/15108/ecm) wrote, DOSEMU supports this, using `-t` or `-dumb`. This works with [the original DOSEMU](http://www.dosemu.org/) and [DOSEMU2](https://dosemu2.github.io/dosemu2/).

`-dumb` runs DOS programs in “dumb” terminal mode, where output goes to DOSEMU’s standard output and can thus be scrolled back in your terminal or redirected. `-t` uses [S-Lang](http://jedsoft.org/slang/) to provide an emulation of a PC text-mode screen inside the terminal, with colours, graphical characters, and mouse integration.

Here’s the Turbo C++ IDE running in DOSEMU in GNOME Terminal with full mouse support:

[image: DOSEMU running Turbo C++ in GNOME Terminal]

Comment: Excellent suggestion. DOSEMU makes a quite good attempt at running DOS text applications, including full-screen TUI applications (DOS Edit, Turbo Vision stuff), in unix terminals. Read the documentation on how to enter keyboard combinations not directly supported by your terminal (like Alt-F9 or so).

Comment: I like the fact that all the things done back then to get as far away from serial port speed is now being captured to be able to go over a serial port :)  (except that a modern computer can do ssh as fast as the network allows)

Comment: Another vote for DOSemu here. It's a sufficiently good emulation that in the past I've used it to drive a parallel-port-connected EPROM programmer from its (closed-source) DOS application.

Answer (score 9):

There's also ecm's fork of 8086tiny, [ecm-pushbx/8086tiny: ecm's repository for 8086tiny: a tiny PC emulator/virtual machine](https://github.com/ecm-pushbx/8086tiny). Unlike dosemu, it runs on an emulated (not virtual) processor so will run on more hosts. [keaston/cp437: Emulates an old-style "code page 437" / "IBM-PC" character set terminal on a modern UTF-8 terminal emulator.](https://github.com/keaston/cp437) is supposed to be a useful wrapper for it.

Comment: This also works with the original 8086tiny!

Comment: Indeed it does. I suggested ecm's fork because this site tends to lean towards development and having the trace flag available is handy for debugging.

Comment: Yup, ecm’s fork is much more useful than the original; I only wanted to point out that this particular feature wasn’t specific to ecm’s fork.